# Find matching elements based on given string

Tags: python

Given I have this list for simplicity.

```
lst = ['db', 'ca', 'db', 'ae', 'ec', 'sa']
```

and the string `'dbaeec'` which will always be even length mostly 6 or 8.

We will split it into 2 length chunks, then take the first `'db'`
find it, but with the condition that,  the element next to it needs to be `'ae'` then after that `'ec'`

Based on the list above we see '**db**' at index 0 and 2.

The first one doesn't match '**ae**' for their next element and should be ignored, but the latter does, even for the third '**ec**' and so the output should be `2`.

This is what I tried so far,

```
for i, n in enumerate(lst): 
  if n == 'db': 
      if lst[i+1] == 'ae':
          if lst[i+2] == 'ec':
              print(i)
              break
```

but surely there must be better/pythonic way?

Comment: Join the list into a string, find the search string in the joined list, return half of that index.

Answer (score 1):

Get 3`(len(string)//2)` elements each time convert it to a string and compare with the `teststring`.

```
lst = ['db', 'ca', 'db', 'ae', 'ec', 'sa']    
teststring= "dbaeec"
for i in range( len(lst)-len(string)//2 ):
    if "".join( lst[i:i+len(string)//2] ) == teststring:
        print(i, i+len(string)//2)
        break
```

Output:

```
2 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a `regex`-based solution.  I made it into a reusable function.

```
import re
test_lst = ['db', 'ca', 'db', 'ae', 'ec', 'sa']
test_pat = 'dbaeec'

def find_match_index(needle, haystack):
    m = re.search(needle, ''.join(haystack))
    try:
        return (m.span()[0])/2
    except AttributeError:
        return None

def test(pat, lst):
    match = find_match_index(pat, lst)
    if match is None:
        print("No match was found (function returned None)")
    else:
        print(f"Found match at list index {match}")

print("Test with test data")
test(test_pat, test_lst)
print("Test with non-matchable pattern")
test('x', test_lst)

#output
Test with test data
Found match at list index 2.0
Test with non-matchable pattern
No match was found (function returned None)
```

This makes use of the fact Python is a dynamic typed language, returning `None` for no match.  Caller must test for this return.  This is because you could have a valid match at index zero, thus zero cannot be a flag for not found.

I am not a fan of manipulating types this way, coming from a C background.  There is no law against this in python, but it comes with risks in future code maintenance.  If I had more time and this was a bigger project, I would make a "Result" class to keep to one type per variable.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

This will check if the sequence of `dbaeec` exists in the list at any consecutive positions.

```
lst = ['db', 'ca', 'db', 'ae', 'ec', 'sa']    
s = 'dbaeec'

if s in ''.join(lst):
    print ('yes')
else:
    print ('no')
```

If you also want to find the index position in the list, you can do:

```
lst = ['db', 'ca', 'db', 'ae', 'ec', 'sa']    
s = 'dbaeec'

i = ''.join(lst).find(s) #do a find after converting the list into a string (using join function) and then searching for dbaeec

if i >= 0:
    print ('Yes, {} is in the list starting index position {}'.format(s,int(i/2)))
else:
    print ('{} is not in the list'.format(s))
```

The output will be:

```
Yes, dbaeec is in the list starting index position 2
```

Note that the above code will only search for the first occurrence in the list. If you want to find all occurrences, the code has to be modified a bit.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
y = "dbaeec"
lst = ['db', 'ca', 'db', 'ae', 'ec', 'sa']

x = ''.join(lst)    
for i in range(0, len(x), 2):
    if x[i:i+len(y)] == y:
        print(i/2)
```

output:

```
2
```